# Verify encryption of rest secrets [etcd] in Openshift v4

Tags: openshift

I got this instruction on how to encrypt at rest of Openshift 4 secrets.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.14/security/encrypting-etcd.html

But there's no verification provided.  Only this,

```
EncryptionCompleted
All resources encrypted: oauthaccesstokens.oauth.openshift.io, oauthauthorizetokens.oauth.openshift.io
```

In kubernetes there's a way to verify it with,

```
kubectl -n kube-system exec -it etcd-master -- sh -c xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx etcdctl --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379 get /registry/secrets/namespace/secret-name"
```

But since openshift is not using kube-system to store it etcd pod.

What should be the equivalent checking of secrets if it's really encrypted?

Thanks!